# How to include an integer into another variable's name

Tags: java, string, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic variable names Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805843/dynamic-variable-names-java)

if i have an

```
int i =5;
```

how to make a new variable, which will have a value of the previous integer build into it's name?

example:

```
String string**i**;

so that, in the ent, my String variable will be named 

string**5**
```

Comment: You don't. Why do you want to? Why not use an array or map?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable names Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805843/dynamic-variable-names-java).  Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/dynamic-variable-names-in-java.  Or many others.

Comment: Yep.  The proper solution here is "use an array," not "hack this into Java," which is impossible.

Comment: int i =5;
String string*+(Integer)i.ToString()+* = "";

Comment: If you do this within a loop it will still wor.

Comment: @TejaswiRana: Are we talking about the same language?  You _can't do that in Java._

Comment: Well I was curious if there was a way :)

Comment: ok. it is not possible to assign names dynamically.

Comment: I suppose it would have been possible if String class had a constructor or a setter method that would allow naming.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  You use an array:

```
String[] strings = new string[10];
strings[5] = "foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't / shouldn't try to do that kind of stuff in Java.  Java variable names must be known at compile time.  Period.

---

And in this particular case, it seems like it would be a pointless exercise anyway.  Consider this:

```
String buildstring_<buildNumber> = ...
```

How are you going to use this hypothetical variable?

```
if (buildstring_<buildNumber>.equals(...)) {
    ....
}
```

But you could have achieved the same thing like this:

```
String buildstring_current = ...

if (buildstring_current.equals(...)) {
    ....
}
```

OK, so suppose there are lots of these build strings ...

```
String buildstring_1 = ...
String buildstring_2 = ...
String buildstring_3 = ...

if (buildstring_<buildNumber>.equals(...)) {
    ....
}
```

Fine ... but what happens when `<buildNumber>` is one greater than the last `buildstring_?` declaration?  Compilation error or runtime error!!!

No.  The sensible way to do this in Java is to use an array or a `Map` ... or possibly something read from a properties file.