# Is there a more efficient way to create new variables in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

If you have an ArrayList (named `al` in this case), and you're looking to get the first five elements of the list as variables, you could do this:

```
    String x1 = al.get(0);
    String x2 = al.get(1);
    String x3 = al.get(2);
    String x4 = al.get(3);
    String x5 = al.get(4);
```

However, using a for loop, is there a way you could do something like this instead:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    String namer = "x" + i.toString();
    String [value of String 'namer'] = al.get(i-1);
}
```

Or is there a completely different method that is much more efficient?

Comment: If you have them in a list, why would you want them as separate variables? Why not just write `al.get(2)` any place you would write `x3`? If that's too verbose, you could put them in an array instead of a list (or just get an array from the list) and write `a[2]`.

Comment: Also, you can't do dynamic variables like what you're showing in Java.  I mean, I suppose you could with reflection, but that is waaay overcomplicating this.

Comment: No, not even reflection can mess with local variable names.  Field names, maybe, but you have to declare all the field names up front

Comment: @sma I think this was essentially the question I was asking, I just wasn't sure how to articulate it. I think my real question _was_ in fact "can you create dynamic variables in java".

Comment: The short answer is no, depending on what you are trying to achieve. You could copy the first five elements to a native array, but there is no point to that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable names Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805843/dynamic-variable-names-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic metaprogramming is not possible in java. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there would be various options.

If you are trying to work in batches of 5 items, the cleanest solution is the one you are using now. If code duplication bothers you as much as it bothers me, then you are looking into [Views in Java Collections Framework](http://softwarecave.org/2014/03/19/views-in-java-collections-framework/), specifically the "View of a portion of a collection" section:

```
List<String> nextFive = list.subList(5, 10);
```

Comment: Another option is apparently an associative array `Map<Strinng,String> props = new HashMap<>(); ... ; props.put("x"+i, al.get(i-1))`. But this code stinks and fetching by index alone from sublist is much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `String` array of size 6 and do the following:

```
String[] str = new String[6];
for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    a[i] = al.get(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to literally create variables on the local stack dynamically you would need to use reflection both ways (if it is even possible, which I don't think it is), otherwise it wouldn't compile then I would stick with the rule of thumb of  [Don't optimize unless you need to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes)

If you are trying to create a reference to variables you can use a map

```
Map variables = new HashMap();
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    variables.put("x"+i, al.get(i-1));
}
```

Then you can access like this

```
variables.get("x1"); //or x2,x3,x4
```

Comment: I believe optimisation is going the other way around here, as @mrkalel is trying to roll an unrolled loop. It is mostly a matter of code replication.

Comment: @PriksoNAI see what you are saying, but the question asked for a more efficient way to declare local variables, and if repeating some code makes the code more maintainable then creating some obscure reflection based monster I would rather just deal with the replication to be honest

Comment: I hardly disagree, as the presented way is also the most efficient way already. I mere assume that there is a misalignment between the question's intentions and its title.

Comment: @PriksoNAI I updated the answer to answer what I think the OP wanted, basically can be done using a map

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just iterate through the ArrayList and break when you have reach the correct number of variables?

```
int i = 0;
for (Object obj : al) {
    if (i > 5) { break; }
    results.append(obj); // append the first five elements to the result
}
```

This, to my knowledge, is the quickest way to do it, since I believe the `get()` method is O(n). So expliciting writing a `get()` would prompt n! calls for the first n objects.

Comment: The `get` method in Java for an array  list is `O( 1 )` get for linked list is `O( n )`, not a Java guy but think that the spinning up of the iterator also uses resources and you are not incrementing i in the answer

Comment: _The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time._ [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html]

Answer (score 1):

"Perhaps" you don't want to do this in practice, but you could (all from within your program):

1. write the boxed source code (`String x1 = ...`) as a proper class to a `*.java` file (with adjustments as needed)
2. run the Java compiler to derive a corresponding `*.class` file
3. class-load the class from that `*.class` file into your program and use it