# Instatiating a class in java as a string

Tags: java, oop

```java
  public Spaces(int a,String b,String c){//Constuctor for Dinos.
    String ds= "d" + a;
    Dino ds = new Dino(a,b,c);
  }
```

Consider that I want to create classes named d1,d2,d3,d4. How can I do this?

Comment: "Consider that I want to create classes named d1,d2,d3,d4". What does that mean?
If you want to create a Class<?> dynamically, that's called runtime bytecode generation.

Comment: Like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5805843/4636715 ?

Comment: You might want to look into reflection api.

Comment: You probably don’t want that. Is this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible in the way you're thinking, but instead of that you can use a simple array.

```
Dino[] dinos = new Dino[4];
dino[1]= new Dino(a,b,c); //e.g. of array use
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java) you can find more info about array declaration. Please also consider to learn to use data structure before doing anything in your code ( for example you can learn [here how to use arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays.asp)).

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a "name" instance variable to Dino

```
class Dino {

    private String name;

    private int a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    public Dino(String name, int a, String b, String c;) {
        this.name = name;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    // ...
}
```

You could then add some Dinos to a list:

```
List<Dino> dinos = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    dinos.add(new Dino("d" + i, 1, "2", "3"));
}
```

Then retrieve the ones you want later:

```
Dino d2 = dinos.stream()
    .filter(d -> d.getName().equals("d2"))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Dino not found"));
```